# Update data from table database SQL Server through Shiny app

Tags: r, sql-server, shiny, shiny-reactivity

I want to develop an app with shiny and I have just started with R(so you can imagine...).

Right now I managed to connect my shiny app to Microsoft SQL Server(through DBI library) and show one of the 3 tables I have on this database.

The goal is to allow the user to click on the rows and change data on it. In this case only one column which takes only 1 or 0 as values. I managed to create the button but I am not able to allow the app to let me click on the row and change the data.

Here is the code I have so far:

```html
# Load libraries
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(RODBC)
library(odbc)
library(pool)
library(DBI)


# connect database
con = DBI::dbConnect(odbc::odbc(), 
                     Driver = "SQL Server", 
                     Server = "MyServer", 
                     Database = "test", 
                     Trusted_Connection = "True")


# Start the dashboard
ui = dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = 'My_first_App'),
  
  dashboardSidebar(
    sidebarMenu(
      menuItem("Tables", tabName = "tables", icon = icon("th")),
      menuItem("Perfomance Dashboard", tabName = "dashboard", icon = icon("dashboard"))
    )
  ),
  
  dashboardBody(
    tabItems(
      # item for tables(Table_1 in this case)
      tabItem(tabName = "tables",
              fluidRow(
                box(tableOutput("tbl")),

                # Tick box to allow the user to change data
                box(title = "Column_to_change",
                    checkboxInput("Column_to_change", "Column_to_change", FALSE)),
                
                #action buttons
                actionButton("submit", "Submit"),
                actionButton("new", "New")
              ))
    )
  )
)


server = function(input, output) {
  
  # We get the Table_1 to show all of it
  output$tbl = renderTable({
    sql = "SELECT * FROM Table_1;"
    query = sqlInterpolate(con, sql, id = input$ID)
    dbGetQuery(con, query)
    
  })
  
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: (1) Either you're simplifying your `sql` statement or you do not need `sqlInterpolate`. I recommend the use of `DBI::dbBind` over `sqlInterpolate`, though, for some reason I think it's safer (I might be wrong). (2) A regular table is not editable, last I checked. Perhaps you want [`DT`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/DT/index.html)? (3) I strong suggest you consider a little more reactivity, handling data in one `reactiveVal` or similar and rendering it based on that RV. You'll need interactivity, something you cannot do with `dbGetQuery` inside `renderTable`.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but I don't think I am able to do that. I am very new to R.

Answer (score 0):

You can use DTEdit package for creating editable good quality and looking data tables in shinyApp. Syntax is quiet easy and user friendly.

https://github.com/jbryer/DTedit

```
my.insert.callback <- function(data, row) {
    mydata <- rbind(data, mydata)
    return(mydata)
}

my.update.callback <- function(data, olddata, row) {
    mydata[row,] <- data[1,]
    return(mydata)
}

my.delete.callback <- function(data, row) {
    mydata[row,] <- NULL
    return(mydata)
}


DTedit::dtedit(input, output,
       name = 'mycontacts',
       thedata = mydata,
       edit.cols = c('name', 'email', 'useR', 'notes'),
       edit.label.cols = c('Name', 'Email Address', 'Are they an R user?', 'Additional notes'),
       input.types = c(notes='textAreaInput'),
       view.cols = c('name', 'email', 'useR'),
       callback.update = my.update.callback,
       callback.insert = my.insert.callback,
       callback.delete = my.delete.callback)
```